# How can I select link and then add onclick event to change other elements styling

Tags: javascript, html

I want to know how can I select first,second,third,etc. link from nav. So that I can add onclick event function that changes appearance of Div. Also I have goTo links like index.html#div1. The idea is to click link and the link to navigates us to the div and change it appearance(## Heading ## box-shadow or change background color ), but temporary.
You can check some code over here:     "https://jsfiddle.net/malle/gwq924fu/1/"

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please add more details like HTML and CSS in a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) at best in a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the JavaScript `querySelectorAll()` for the links?

You could use something like:

```js
const links = document.querySelectorAll("a");
```

And to modify its CSS:

```js
links[0].style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

But all the a elements should have the `onClick` defined to your function, so you could use if statements to validate what element you would like to modify.